# Find and replace date within a file

Tags: bash, sed

My apologies if my title is not descriptive enough, I believe the following will be.
I have 3 files which are just plain text, within each file, is a date

```
Date: 2012-08-31 for example
```

I would like to get a command/script to find this and update to the current date, but the date will be ever changing and may not be known going in (without viewing the contents of the file

Knowing what the date is, its simple enough with sed, but how can I do this knowing the syntax of the line I want to modify, but not the specific values. ("`Date:` " at least is unchanging)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your date format is unchanging, and all three files are the only three text files in your PWD, you could use `GNU sed` like this:

```
sed -r 's/Date: [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/Date: 2012-09-01/g' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, for the purpose of scripting it, I went with

        _date=`date +%F`
        sed -i -r 's/Date: [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/Date: '${_date}'/g' *.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
today=`date +%F`
sed -r -i '.bak' "s/Date: [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/Date: $today/g" file1 file2 file3
```